# NameError: name 'display' is not defined

Tags: python, image, display

I try to run python code using Linux terminal to display a png image.but it gives me same error again and again.

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open("/content/sample_1.png")

# Lets display the image

display(im)
```

Comment: What is display? I am not aware of any commonly used function called display in python. Clearly neither is your python interpreter

Comment: display is not a native function in python. It is likely a function you need to import from some module (IPython perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `im.show()` instead of `display()`:

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open("/content/sample_1.png")

# Lets display the image

im.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`display` is a command on the Linux shell, and you can't use in python directly.

If you just want to show the PNG image, you can use the following code:

```
import subprocess
im="/content/sample_1.png"
subprocess.getoutput("display %s" %im)
```